# Filtering queries by by user and role / scoping data

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am using ABP Commercial to implement a custom CRM system. I am looking for an example, a best practice, a library, or even a framework for scoping data according to user IDs and roles.

Simple scoping like just showing entities created by a certain user is fairly straightforward. But what about showing increasingly more broad data based on a hierarchy of user roles.

For example, I might have a basic user role that can only see data created by the user in that role. Then, I might have a manager role that can see his own data and all the data created by the basic users he manages.  Contemplating any decent size organization, you can see how this hierarchy might get quite deep.

So can anyone tell me whether there is a facility or module within ABP Commercial or ABP Framework to facilitate this kind of pattern or if there is third party best practice, library, or framework that might work in conjunction with my code to realize this functionality?

In the past I have written my own implementations but I am looking for a DDD or clean architecture based solution.

EDIT

A more specific example of what I'm trying to do is to create an extension of the user class and role class or to add additional entities managed by a domain service that would allow for:

- users to have a collection of roles they manage and a collection of specific users they manage, and…
- roles to have a collection of other roles they manage (think composite pattern)

These relationships would be used to filter all kinds of queries within my application.

Here are some use cases:

- return a list of contacts associated with the clients of my direct reports
- return a flattened list of all users managed by me or my reports
- return the total revenue of all sales made by users managed by me or my reports